# VC-dimensions of functions from real numbers to {0,1}

Tags: machine-learning

I'm currently studying VC-dimensions. Suppose I have the hypothesis class $H$, where $H = \{ h \in \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{ 0,1 \} \}$. I think this means that the hypothesis class $H$ is a set of classifiers  mapping between real numbers and binary-valued 1 or 0. So the VC-dimension for this one, if I'm not mistaken, would be infinite, right? My intuition is that it can arbitrarily shatter a large number of points (i.e., whichever points and no matter the labelling or how many points chosen, the classifier set $H$ contains a classifier that can correctly label it). Please correct me if I'm wrong with my thoughts! Thank you.

Comment: Just to add on $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{R}$, but I think should be obvious

Answer (score 1):

You are exactly correct. This should be clear from introductory books including [Understanding Machine Learning](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/) and [Foundations of Machine Learning](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Emohri/mlbook/).